# How to delete a file in sailsjs?

Tags: node.js, sails.js, fs, enoent

I've been working on a project where I need to regularly update the associations and database. I'm stuck with the deletion of files.
I used [fs.unlink](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_unlink_path_callback) of [fs](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_file_system) for this purpose, but it throws some error.

Code snippet -

```
fs.unlinkSync("/images/uploadedImages/70c9c2c4-74de-41c1-b096-c403b749a1a9.png");
sails.log.info("Logo deleted succesfully");
```

Error log -

```
fs.js:932
return binding.unlink(pathModule._makeLong(path));
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, unlink '/images/uploadedImages/70c9c2c4-74de-41c1-b096-c403b749a1a9.png'
```

Also the file 70c9c2c4-74de-41c1-b096-c403b749a1a9.png exists in the path /images/uploadedImages/, which is inside the assets folder of sailsjs structure.

Isn't there any way to achieve this?

Comment: The file doesn't exist at the path you've given. Is `/images` a folder on your server's disk? If it's a URL path, the `fs` module doesn't recognize those. You'll need to determine what disk path the URL path corresponds with and provide that to `fs.unlinkSync()`.

Comment: Please debug a little on your own first, seems like a fairly obvious issue

Comment: I've updated the question. As a matter of fact the file exists in the path, yet the error remains.

Answer (score 0):

it seems  file which you passed to `fs.unlinkSync()` doesn't exist
make sure you have this file

> /images/uploadedImages/70c9c2c4-74de-41c1-b096-c403b749a1a9.png

then it will work .

Comment: the file does exist in the path provided, that's the reason why I can't understand the reason behind this error.

Answer (score 0):

Figured out the issue.
Sailsjs framework doesn't start searching for path inside the assets folder by it's own.

Changing the path from - `/images/uploadedImages/70c9c2c4-74de-41c1-b096-c403b749a1a9.png` to `./assets/images/uploadedImages/70c9c2c4-74de-41c1-b096-c403b749a1a9.png` solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If any one still finding the answer, below can be the good approach if you want to do some operation on file.

with [fs.access](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_access_path_mode_callback) you can check whether file is available or not before you do any operation on file. One can use [fs.accessSync](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_accesssync_path_mode) also for Synchronous behaviour.

In below example, i have used [fs.unlink](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_unlink_path_callback) but one can also use [fs.unlinkSync](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_unlinksync_path) for deletion of file.

```js
// import in file
const fs = require('fs')

// path of your file
let path = 'path to your file'

// fs.access will check if file is available or not
fs.access(path, fs.F_OK, (err) => {
    if (err) {
      console.error(err)
      return
    }
    //file exists, Go for delete operation
    fs.unlink(path , function (err) {
        if (err) {
            console.error(err);
            return
        }
        console.log('Image File has been Deleted');
    });
})
```